# Android Geofence Delay (10-20seconds)

Tags: android, performance, gps, android-geofence

I have built an Android app with Geofences following the instructions from the [developer training](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html). I have tested my app several times during the production proccess with mock locations - it worked like a charm. However, when i tested my app with real location data (always with GPS enabled) the app showed a **delay of 10-20 seconds after entering or leaving a geofence**. My first thought was that the GPS signal might be inaccurate. But I later added Google Maps to my app and I can now see the accuracy of the **GPS-signal** according to the circle around my current location - all **should be fine**.

Has anybody faced a similar problemor know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I got even bigger delays. Ended up adding my own implementation on top of geofencing, manually calculating distances to the nearest set of entities and trigger enter/exit events. My guess is that the evaluation of geofences internally in the OS is independent of received GPS locations for battery optimization reasons.

Comment: should i check manually or can i use mLocationManager.addProximityAlert() ? Looks like the same as a Geofence

Comment: @cYrixmorten i need to detect someone  within a 15-20 meter radius and I'm having the same issues. i implemented my own geofencing but detecting exit is buggy. its difficult bc also the location w/ wifi jumps around 5-15 meters sometimes. how are you manually triggering google apis geofence enter transition. i want to manually trigger enter and let the api trigger exit...

Comment: @Jisike I find the closet point wrt my points of interest for each two location updates. That is, I always look one step back to draw a line which triggers an enter event if intersecting the radius  of a poi.